# Корректно ли построена фраза?

Tags: падежи, орфография

Рекомендованы в городе и длительных поездок

Answer (score 2):

Фраза непонятная, построена неправильно.

Answer (score 1):

Фраза некорректна как стилистически, так и грамматически. Рекомендованы (в чем) городе и в длительных поездк***ах***, а не поездок. Что касается стилистики, то непонятно, что рекомендовано.